Как решить HTTP Error 500.30 при деплое?
При деплое на удалённый сервер получаю ошибку HTTP Error 500.30, полный текст ошибки:

HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start
Common solutions
to this issue:
The app failed to start
The app started but then stopped
The app started but threw an exception during startup
Troubleshooting steps:
Check the system event log for error messages
Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect
For more guidance on
diagnosing and handling these errors, visit Troubleshoot ASP.NET Core
on Azure App Service and IIS.

В логах только это:
Unhandled exception. System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Could not load file or assembly 'CMS.Domain, Version=1.0.24302.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_DefinedTypes()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.AssemblyPart.get_Types()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFeatureProvider.PopulateFeature(IEnumerable`1 parts, ControllerFeature feature)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateFeature[TFeature](TFeature feature)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcCoreMvcBuilderExtensions.AddControllersAsServices(IMvcBuilder builder)
   at CMS.Web.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in D:\Visual Studio Local\CMS\CMS.Web\Startup.cs:line 64
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InterpretedInvoke_Method(Object obj, IntPtr* args)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeDirectByRefWithFewArgs(Object obj, Span`1 copyOfArgs, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeWithOneArg(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.InvokeCore(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<Invoke>g__Startup|0(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<Build>b__0(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.UseStartup(Type startupType, HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services, Object instance)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<UseStartup>b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.InitializeServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at CMS.Web.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Visual Studio Local\CMS\CMS.Web\Program.cs:line 11
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CMS.Domain, Version=1.0.24302.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. 
The system cannot find the file specified.

File name: 'CMS.Domain, Version=1.0.24302.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
64-я строчка:
services.AddMvc(options => // <-- 64 строка
{
    options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
})
.AddControllersAsServices()
.SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Latest)
.AddFluentValidation(fv =>
{
    fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>();
    fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<LoginUserVmValidator>();
})

Локально всё запускается отлично без проблем и ошибок вообще на различных конфигурациях. Сам Startup не менялся уже пол года как.
UPD:
Библиотека .Domain присутствует на сервере


С AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute я помню у меня тоже что-то не срослось, но подробностей уже не помню. Помню только, что так и не заработало нормально.

@CrazyElf, да, Antiforgery стоит уже давно, но такого не было раньше. Посмотрел по коммитах, последнее изменение Startup более полугода назад

А ошибка сама какая? Я вижу StackTrace, но на что именно ругается, что-то не вижу в вопросе. Также смотрите, как и советуют Check the system event log for error messages. Пока это просто "Вот тут что-то произошло", а что, додумывайте самостоятельно.

@EvgeniyZ, А ошибка сама какая? Я вижу StackTrace, но на что именно ругается, что-то не вижу в вопросе. - ругается на 64ю строку в Startup. 64 строчка это именно services.AddMvc(options =>

Любая ошибка в C# - это например такое: System.FormatException: "Входная строка имела неверный формат." - как видите, есть "тип" и есть описание, в котором сказано что именно не понравилось системе. Дальше уже, в этой ошибки есть StackTrace, который показывает цепочку вызовов, по которому можно узнать где упало. Вот "где" мы знаем, а "что произошло" нет, вы это не показали. Так что, ищите. Если нашли стактрейс, то чуть выше должен быть и "заголовок" с типом и описанием ошибки.

Да, либо выше либо ниже обрезано что-то важное. Самой ошибки тут нет, нужна ошибка.

@CrazyElf, прошу прощения. Дополнило лог

@EvgeniyZ, прошу прощения. Дополнило лог

Ну вот теперь смотрите что у вас там не так. Для начала, проверьте, указанная библиотека содержащая в себе CMS.Domain вообще существует? Подключена к проекту? Она 32 или 64, если 32, то включен-ли в IIS (или где вы там хостите) поддержка x32? А права на этот файл у сервера есть? Ну и так далее... Вариантов уйма почему не могло загрузить.

@EvgeniyZ, да, всё есть, всё на месте. Скрин добавлю в вопрос

А в файле web.,config что? Он хоть стандартный? Модуль ASP.NET Core используется встроенный или отдельным процессом?

И у вас на скрине первая буква обрезана, или её и правда нету?

@PavelMayorov, обрезана
